# Which context used when launching a coroutine in GlobalScope without further specification?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

Is this a good way of loading image-resources? Or is it done wrong?

```
val url = "https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885_960_720.jpg"
imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView) 

var request = ImageRequest.Builder(applicationContext)
            .data(url)
            .memoryCachePolicy(CachePolicy.ENABLED)
            .error(com.google.android.material.R.drawable.mtrl_ic_error)
            .target(imageView)
            .build()
GlobalScope.launch {
            val disposable = imageLoader.execute(request)
}
```

In which context will the coroutine be executed?

Which context will be used for assigning the loaded image-data to the UI-control? It isn't necessary using `withContext(Dispatchers.IO)`?

Comment: use glide tp load image, you dont even need coroutine just to show image

Comment: This is actually the reason Dispatchers.Default is named "Default". It's the default one for GlobalScope and other scopes where the associated CoroutineContext doesn't include a dispatcher.